# Tkinter in Python 3.6: Grid sticky option not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm a very very new to Python and was trying to develop a GUI in Python to help automating some of my work. I've looked at a few older posts in this forum and others, but couldn't find my mistake.

I'm trying to make a label text centered using the `.grid()` method, both in the window that pops but also keep it centered if the user resizes it. The main suggestion I've found online was to use the `.grid_rowconfigure()` method and give a non 0 weight to the relevant row, but that doesn't seems to be working.

I've created an alternate test code that has the same problem to avoid posting a wall of code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TestApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="TEST")
        label.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
        label.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

TestApp().mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Calling `grid_rowconfigure()` on the label would only affect widgets contained WITHIN the label.  To affect the label itself, you have to call this method on its parent (which is `self` in your test code).

Fixed code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TestApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="TEST")
        label.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

TestApp().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give the relevant row a non-zero weight, you can give the other rows a non-zero weight:

```
label = tk.Label(self, text="TEST")
label.grid(row=1, column=1)
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```